# Is jucheck.exe a virus?

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, virus

I keep getting a message from Windows that a program jucheck.exe is trying to connect to the internet. The message shows the publisher of the program as 'Unknown'. Is it a Virus? How to remove this?

Comment: Related question: [How to stop jucheck from running?](http://superuser.com/questions/130961/how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automati)

Comment: Note that the message is likely not from Windows but from an overly zealous personal firewall. Normally you won't get any weird panicky warnings from Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Juscheck.exe and Jusched.exe are Java processes that schedule updates. They can be given access to the internet. If you're still unsure, run a full system scan with your virusscanner. Usually these processes are harmless.

Comment: ANYthing can become infected, if a hacker tries hard enough, but BloodPhilia is right; normally these are innocuous enough.

Comment: if jucheck.exe is from Sun why does it not show Publisher as Sun Microsystems?

Comment: @Amitabh: Probably because it is not signed. Some publishers sign their executable files, but most don't.

Comment: Something from Java should have been signed by Sun? It is really hard to allow a program which is not signed to make changes in the computer

Comment: Tha majority of the non-MS-developed programs are unsigned...

Comment: I've seen jusched, but never jucheck. What version(s) of Java are you running?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the website [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) to upload and test any suspicious executable.

This site will verify the file using (at the moment) 39 anti-virus engines.

If that many anti-virus products vote for this file as not infected, there's an excellent chance that it's really not a virus.

Answer (score 2):

> The jucheck.exe is the Java update verification process. This process will check on the internet for available updates for the Java software installed on your computer. If updates are available, it will notify you and/or manage the download and install of the updates. You should leave this process running in order to keep your Java up to date.

Source: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jucheck.xml

The path to find the file on a 64 bit Windows 7 computer is as follows:

```
C:\\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\jucheck.exe
```

don't forget to go to folder options and uncheck hide computer hard disk files and check show hidden files.  Once done you can restore folder options back to default.