# How to get along with Java updates (Windows)

Tags: windows, java, updates, auto-updates

We've learned how to [disable automatic java updates](https://superuser.com/questions/130961/how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automati), but whether we update Java manually or automatically, is there a way to make it less annoying?

Personally, I wouldn't mind Java updating automatically every day, if it would just stop bothering me about it.

Problems:

1. When Java thinks it's time to update, it won't leave you alone until you've done it.
2. Java doesn't know that an update is an update and not a new installation - each version lives happily next to the previous ones on Windows.
3. Since each update is a new installation, it won't remember any settings from previous installations: one second of attention failure might mean you've suddenly got a new toolbar in your browser. Also, auto updates might be back to default, meaning daily update checks.

Any takes on this? Is there a way to coexist with Java updates on Windows?

Comment: Your seconds point is not true for current releases. They all install into the "jre6" directory and there replace older versions. Only versions older than about 2 years do install themself side-by-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head over to [Ninite.com](http://www.ninite.com) and create yourself a (free for home use) installer with Java JRE as your selection.

Each time you run this installer it will download the newest version of Java JRE and install it (if needed).  You can then setup a Windows task to run the installer every night, or once a week or something.

Some applicable info from Ninite's site:

> **Always Up-to-date** - A Ninite installer always gets an app's latest version no matter when you made it.
>
> **No Toolbars** - Ninite automatically says "No" to toolbars and other junk.
>
> **It Updates Too** - Just run your Ninite installer again and it will update the apps to their latest versions.

They also have a new, purchasable [auto-updater utility](https://ninite.com/updater/) for your task tray.