# How to disable the Java update message balloon in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, java

I've looked in the Java section of the Control Panel, but don't see an obvious way to disable the automatic message balloon that pop up in Windows 7 asking me to update my version of Java. How do I disable them?

Comment: This will work on all Windows versions: 1) Download Autoruns from Sysinternals. 2) Search for "jucheck" using the search field at the top. 3) Uncheck "SunJavaUpdateSched".

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't disable the update notifier. Instead, change preferences for how often you'd like to be notified of newer versions.

At java website you have all the information you need.

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml

After reading the doc, if you still want to disable the notification, do the following:

1. Start regedit.
2. Navigate through to the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy
3. Change the
   value of EnableAutoUpdateCheck to 0 and the value of
   EnableJavaUpdate to 0.

Also for 64bit users:

1. Start Regedit
2. Navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy
3. Change the value of EnableJavaUpdate to 0.
4. Change the value of NotifyDownload to 0
5. Create a new DWORD of EnableAutoUpdateCheck and set the value to 0.

Done

Answer (score 5):

1 - open JAVA control panel by type java in start menu! (Run as Administrator) [Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfZR.png)

2 - on update tab deselect(uncheck) "check for update automatically" [image]

3- Select " Do not Check"[image]

4 - all Done!

Comment: This doesn't actually work. If you go back into the control panel after making that change, you'll see that it doesn't "stick". This is the correct answer: http://serverfault.com/a/26568

Comment: Same here, this does not work.  I'm not going to downvote because it would be a correct answer if the idiots who distribute the Java weren't busy running it into the ground.

Comment: This works if you have never installed Java i.e. it uses the one provided by Windows.  It stops working when you either install the JRE or JDK.

Comment: Make sure to run configure java as Administrator, otherwise, the do not check will stay un-checked.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the notification settings in the Java Control Panel did not help, than it is probably not possible. Check the Update tab of the Java Control Panel. Uncheck "Check for Updates Automatically"

Your best course of action may be to uninstall Java completely if you are not using it. Java is the most widely exploited plugin on a computer and running an out of date version that is plugged in to the browser is very risky. The reason there are so many updates is because it is very problematic and unsafe software to use in a browser.

You can customize the notifications in Windows 7 by clicking the arrow in the Notification Center/System Tray and selecting Customize. You can scroll to the Java icon and change the behavior to "Hide icon & Notifications"