# Java asks daily if I want a update on Win7

Tags: windows-7, java

I get a daily Java popup that asks if it can make changes to my computer. (Win7 Professional, 64bit).

I still want Java to be able to do automatic updates but I don't want to be notified each day.

I found these topics regarding how to disable updates: [how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automat](https://superuser.com/questions/130961/how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automat) and [cant-seem-to-disable-java-automatic-update](https://serverfault.com/questions/14303/cant-seem-to-disable-java-automatic-update/26568#26568).

However, I don't want to disable Java updates but I only want to get a notification each month or so. In the Java-control panel I clicked Update -> Advanced Settings -> Frequency: Montly. But it doesnt work. I found the same question here: [java-popup-drives-me-insane](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/174672-java-popup-drives-me-insane.html)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Verify that the problem is not solved by first installing the current version of Java.  If it does not then report the problem to Oracle.

Comment: I had Java updates disabled for a long time because of this nonsense.  The updates try to slip in a bunch of other junk that you must be vigilant to decline.  They continuously push the "updates" even though there is nothing changed in Java to get the revenue from people installing the crapware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when Java asked for an a update and I pressed 'yes' nothing happened. Therefore, on a restart I was asked again for an update.

To solve this problem, I had to manually double click on the Java-Icon at the task bar after pressing 'yes'. Then, I could proceed with the installation of the update and wasn't bothered anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if you have different versions of java installed on your computer. It may be some old version of it that keep asking for updates. To quickly access Program and Features,  press **windows key + r** and type **appwiz.cpl**.