# How do I run a JAR file without installing Java?

Tags: windows, java

My question may seem odd but this is indeed what I need to do. For the first in the last (maybe) 10 years I have to run a JAR file in my computer. But I don't want to install 'the Java' (and all those things it adds into your system). How can I run that JAR file?

Comment: 1. Too broad. Differs for each application. 2. That's asking for a recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: You can manually uncheck the box every time you install or update. Alternatively, you can [disable it using the registry](http://www.studiofuga.com/2013/03/26/annoying-crapware-on-java-updates-a-k-a-ask-com-toolbar/).

Comment: This depends on each individual application.

Comment: We don't solve questions by putting "solved" in the title. You should wait for @nixda to post his answer.

Comment: Even if your question was actually [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): the above is not a duplicate of [the one you voted for](http://superuser.com/questions/130961/how-to-stop-jucheck-from-running-java-wont-remember-check-for-updates-automat). What are you trying to achieve with your edits of the title and that close vote? Given your reputation on SO I guess you know, but please remember that all Stack Exchange sites try to be a useful resource for future visitors.

Comment: (Even more, I think it's a good question, which just makes me more curious...)

Comment: "install" java is nothing more than putting a java executable and some other basic jars somewhere on your filesystem, you might end up using just another JVM environment to load your own JARs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two options

---

1. Use [jPortable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) together with [jPortable Launcher](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable_launcher)

   > jPortable Launcher allows you to easily run Java JARs from your PortableApps.com-enabled device with the jPortable portable Java Runtime Environment installed.

   To use this, visit PortableApps.com and search for jPortable . A list of result should come up and then select the runtime environment and the launcher (links above). Then download both of them, and install per directions. A folder will be created where the downloaded files were run from. Inside one of them will be "JavaPortableLauncher.exe". If you launch it, you should be able to locate and open a jar file with the application.

   [image: The Launcher]

**(or)**

2. Download and extract the [Windows x86 tar.gz version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and start your .JAR file from commmand line: `start C:\Java\bin\javaw.exe -jar C:\myfolder\myprogram.jar`

Comment: 2 is not ok because it implies to install (now or in the past) Java on the 'another PC'. But 1 works.

Comment: If you are concerned or have no access to a second machine, you could always install Java in a VM, backup the Java folder and uninstall Java again. I'm using the secondf approach for almost every Java program I'd like to run

Comment: Just wanted to add the comment that option two works now (edit from 2016)/Oracle offers directly the tar.gz file. I almost dismissed that second option after reading the comments from 2014.

Comment: I have the Java runtime (jPortable) installed on my device/PortableApps/CommonFiles/Java. Where should I install the JPortable launcher? Same folder?

Comment: could you please help here https://superuser.com/q/1518268/675927 ? thanks

Answer (score 7):

I remember that severel years ago you could download Java, unzip it, put it somewhere in a folder, and by pointing to the java executable in that folder you could run java. I don't know how it works today with the current versions, but I wouldn't be surprised if it still could work like that. Don't have Windows here, so can't test it, but you can download a zip (or tar.gz) file, unzip that and than work from there. If you can't unzip gz files, download and install 7-zip.

This won't install it like you normally do, so no update alerts etc, no browser integration, no system variables, but you need something to run that code, and this is the least I think.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Download one of the tar.gz versions.

Comment: +1 Didn't know they offer a tar.gz packet

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571736/355364) just worked for me:

1. download the Java installer for whatever version you want;
2. open it with 7-zip;
3. locate and extract the tools.zip file (it can be in different directories, depending on Java version, build, or if it is a JDK or JRE);
4. expand tools.zip in some ;
5. go into  and run `for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar`;
6. try running `bin/java -version`.

If it works, thats it, you have got yourself a portable JAVA_HOME.

Comment: which "Java Installer" are you talking about?

Comment: @sajuuk, I meant the `.exe` you download from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that convert your .jar file into .exe .
follow this :
[JAR2EXE](http://jar2exe.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This looks like it requires Java.

Comment: Indeed this needs Java installed. See the [system requirements at the right side](http://jar2exe.codeplex.com/documentation)