# How to run a Windowed JAR file over SSH without installing JRE and without root access on NetBsd?

Tags: linux, java, 64-bit, x11-forwarding, netbsd

First, I can use Java, but for what I want to achieve (building a database where othe only application supporting the format is in Java), **I need 100Gb of RAM during 20 hours**.

I have access to a server with the required RAM, but not as root and no JRE is available. The same is true for the Xorg libraries.

Here’s the uname :

```
8.0_STABLE NetBSD 8.0_STABLE (GENERIC) #0: Sun Feb 24 10:50:49 UTC 2019  mkrepro@mkrepro.NetBSD.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC amd64
```

The Linux layer is installed, but nothing else is installed : not even Glibc, so the only applications which can be run are the ones which are statically compiled.

So not only Java isn’t Installed, but some of the require shared libraries are missing…
However, I have full write access to my $HOME directory, and I can run my own executables from there.

Is a way to convert a Jar file into a NetBsd Executable or Linux statically linked executable ? I have also the source code of the Jar file if compiling is an acceptable solution.

I only found about ɢᴄᴊ, but I’m unsure if Java 7 is supported…

Comment: I already know about https://superuser.com/q/745112 but it’s for Windows…

Comment: You could maybe download Java from Oracle and simply extract the tar file in your home directory, and then set up the JAVA_HOME and other env. variables.  Not sure about getting X11 forwarding over ssh working though, not sure how much X11 is needed on the remote side...

Comment: @ivanivan as far I’m aware, the Oracle version doesn’t exists for Netʙꜱᴅ and the Linux version isn’t statically linked. **Also, why the close vote ?**.

Comment: Not sure on the close vote, I didn't cast it.  At this point though I'd say "check out linode.com they offer VMs with enough RAM for your purposes for less than $1/hr and you can get a $10 free credit when you sign up".

Comment: @ivanivan though, I also need 20Gb of disk space and network and the 20 hours ᴄᴘᴜ time is for a i7‑4700 which means faster ᴄᴘᴜ would takes less times while faster ones would take more.

Comment: @ivanivan where do you see the $10 free credit ? Is there a promotional code ? Otherwise the current sever I want to use without Java is free (the aim is to not prevent the activity of other users).

Comment: Code is on the various documentation pages on their site, especially the "getting started" one :)..  anyway, it is **DOCS10**.  Gotta admit, I've been a super satisfied customer for 14 or 15 years and love their service, and have my students use it for a course on network services w/ linux.

Comment: @ivanivan though turns out Azure is 40% cheaper about ʀᴀᴍ if using West ᴜꜱ2 location. The rule with the free server of the question is you can do what you want if power and ʀᴀᴍ is available (a bit like GitHub storage), but there’s no root access to prevent abuse. But they still offer gopher and ꜰᴛᴘ hosting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97655/discussion-between-ivanivan-and-user2284570).

Comment: @ivanivan with root access you always have full control. And ɪᴅ Required ? I’m out !
It seems I need a way to find a way to run a jar without java on Netʙꜱᴅ then.