# How do I run Java from a usb key by using JPortable and its launcher?

Tags: java, portable-apps, launcher, runtime

I downloaded both the [Java runtime environment](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) and the [JPortable launcher](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable_launcher_64) from *PortableApps.com* in order to run Java and edit projects by launching the IDE from my USB key without the need of installation on my local machine.

I put both into a subfolder of my USB key --> `F:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java`

Once I had both the Java runtime environment and the launcher installed in the same place, I run the launcher but the following alert appeared:

[image: error message]

The mentioned URL (*https://portableapps.com/go/jPortable*) is different from the one I downloaded the *.paf*  archive from and is no more available but the file is still the same (see the previous link above).

I reinstalled both and tried to change the directory (I moved the launcher inside/outside the subfolder of the JPortable / Java runtime environment) but nothing changed.

How am I supposed to install JPortable and the launcher in order to run JAVA and edit projects from an external USB drive?

Comment: hello, please did you solve this? same issue here

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it will work for you but it worked for me so here it goes.

When installing the Jportable & Jportable Launcher you have to have them in a specific directory structure so for example mine is:

Jportable `C:\Users\*YourUsernameHere*\Desktop\JavaPortable\CommonFiles\Java`

Jportable Launcher `C:\Users\*YourUsernameHere*\Desktop\JavaPortable\JavaPortableLauncher`

This means that when i installed Jportable & Jportable Launcher with the .paf installers i set the installing directory to be the folder "JavaPortable" (Look at screenshots below for how it should look)

[image: Folder Structure Example]

Comment: Can you add details? This doesn't make sense.